# Watch an api for changes with Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to use the Bitbucket API and then watch it for any changes afterwards. I'm currently `request`:

```
var request = require('request');

var repoUrl = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/example/branch/';

request(repoUrl, function (error, response, body) {
  // stuff happens
});
```

But how could I watch  it for any future changes after the initial request?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do some API polling.